# Use JQuery to count matching html table entries

Tags: jquery

I have logfile data, and I want to use jQuery to count how many entries each "site" has.  Further, I'd like to do something (maybe change the background color of) sites that have multiple entries:

```
<tr><td class='site'>123456</td><td>70</td><td>10.32</td><td>2014-03-04</td></tr>
<tr><td class='site'>123457</td><td>73</td><td>8.95</td><td>2014-03-03</td></tr>
<tr><td class='site'>123458</td><td>61</td><td>1.37</td><td>2014-03-05</td></tr>
<tr><td class='site'>123457</td><td>68</td><td>12.26</td><td>2014-03-04</td></tr>
<tr><td class='site'>123457</td><td>95</td><td>15.31</td><td>2014-03-05</td></tr>
<tr><td class='site'>123456</td><td>58</td><td>1.31</td><td>2014-03-05</td></tr>
<tr><td class='site'>123459</td><td>65</td><td>11.06</td><td>2014-03-05</td></tr>
```

So, from the html above, I would put the following totals into a div:

```
Site    Issues
123456    2
123457    3
123458    1
123459    1
```

...and I would highlight the two sites that have multiple entries (123456 and 123457) in the table.  Can you point me in the right direction?

P.S. I'm already using "tablesorter" to sort the rows.  Really handy plugin!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one of the ways you can do it. [Jsbin Demo](http://jsbin.com/wimixuxi/1/edit?html,js,output)

```
var result = {};

$('.site').each(function(index, element) {
  var $el = $(element);
  var site = $el.html();
  result[site] = result[site] || 0;
  result[site]++; 

  //To highlight sites with multiple issues
  if (result[site] > 1) {
    $el.css({background: 'green'}); //Or something else
  } 
});

console.log(result);
```

**Update**

For a corner case caught by @Eduardo and he suggested the fix as well in the comment.
We should use this to highlight element otherwise we will miss to select the first element in multiple entries.

```
$('.site:contains('+site+')').css({'color': 'green'}); //Or something else
```

Comment: Where do you set `numIssues`?

Comment: `result[site][numIssues] = result[site][numIssues] || 0;`

Comment: That doesn't set the variable `numIssues`. You also never initalize the variable `els`.

Comment: I think you mean `result[site].numIssues` and `result.[site].els`.

Comment: @Barmar yes..I made the typo..You are right..Will update the code.

Comment: You're setting all elements green, not just the ones with multiples.

Comment: Change $el.css  to $(".site:contains("+site+")").css to work properly otherwise it will miss the first element of those that have multiples

Comment: @EduardoQuintana He edited the answer and add the `if()` since my comment.

Comment: Oh ok sorry my bad =) but yeah there is still the issue with the first element css

Comment: @EduardoQuintana Yes Good catch..I need to update the answer again. Really appreciate your catch.

Answer (score 2):

```
var totals = {};
$("td.site").each(function() {
    var site = $(this).text();
    if (totals[site]) {
        totals[site]++;
    } else {
        totals[site] = 1;
    }
}
```

Now the object `totals` contains the counts you want.

Comment: Thank you very much - I was close, but I wanted to match text for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

```
var sites = [];
var rows = $("tr");
for(var i in rows){
    var site = $("td.site", rows[i]).text();
    // if I've already saved this site, i go to the next one
    if(sites[site])continue;

    // i get how many times the site is repeated
    var count = $("td:contains('"+site+"')").length;

    // save result in an array
    sites[site] = count;
    // or display the result somehow
}
```